# Selecionar determinado item de um spinner

Tags: android

Qual o metodo que faz um spinner estar com determinado item selecionado, ex:
tenho os itens:
1
2
3 e
4

e quero que ele inicie com o '3' selecionado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma vez que você criou programaticamente ou obteve o seu **Spinner** através de um layout, basta utilizar o método [`setSelection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int,%20boolean%29) passando a posição desejada como parâmetro:

```
spinner.setSelection(2);
```